# Can't do the insetion in database android

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, insert

There is a problem with insetion in database. I don't know what to do.

It writes error inserting.

```java
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    BaseOpener bo;
    private static final String ML = "ML";
    Button read, write;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        read = (Button) findViewById(R.id.read);
        read.setOnClickListener(this);
        write = (Button) findViewById(R.id.write);
        write.setOnClickListener(this);
        bo = new BaseOpener(this);
        Log.i("Ml", "good start");
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = bo.getWritableDatabase();
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.write:
        {
            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
            Log.i("ML", "write");
            cv.put("id", 1);
            cv.put("name", "Petr");
            cv.put("phone", "911");
            cv.clear();
            db.insert("table1", null, cv);
        }
            break;
        case R.id.read:
        {`enter code here`
            Log.i("ML", "read");
            Cursor c = db.query("table1",null,null,null,null,null,null);
            if(c.moveToFirst()){
                int idColIndex = c.getColumnIndex("id");
                int nameColIndex = c.getColumnIndex("name");
                int emailColIndex = c.getColumnIndex("phone");
                Log.i("ML",
                        "ID = " + c.getInt(idColIndex) + 
                        ", name = " + c.getString(nameColIndex) + 
                        ", phone = " + c.getString(emailColIndex));
            }
        }
            break;
        }
        db.close();
        Log.i("ML", "the base is closed");
    }
}
public class BaseOpener extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public BaseOpener(Context context) {
        super(context, "contacts", null, 1);
        Log.i("ML", "the base is ready");
    }`enter code here`
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("create table table1 (" + "id integer primary key,"
                + "name String," + "phone String" + ");");
        Log.i("ML", "table1 is ready");
    }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us the error of logcat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

clear()
Removes all values. Read more on ContentValues [here](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-tw/reference/android/content/ContentValues.html)

Answer (score 0):

Your table lists id as primary key so you can't insert it twice.  I would just comment out the cv.put("id",1) line and let sqlite handle it.

```
//cv.put("id", 1);

db.execSQL("create table table1 (" + "id integer primary key,"
            + "name String," + "phone String" + ");");
    Log.i("ML", "table1 is ready");
```

Also from your next app on consider naming your id column _id.  This will make the table more compatible with cursor adapters and such.

Look at these links they all use _id

[cursorAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html) [ContentProvider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics.html)  [ListView](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html)